# Div not showing on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, display

So, I'm trying to make this so when I hover over the image, the div appears. Unfortunately, I am not able to get it to do so, and I'm at a loss as to why it's not working.

Here is my code:

```css
.summary:hover {
  opacity: .6;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.summaryOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 280px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #E7DFDD;
  color: #0E0B16;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: .9;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.summary:hover .summaryOverlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftAlign" id="lastWish">
  <img class="summary" alt="the last wish" src="lastWish.jpg" style="width: inherit; height: inherit;" />
</div>
<div class="summaryOverlay">
  Geralt is a witcher.
  <br><br> &nbsp;Yet he is no ordinary killer-for-hire.
  <br><br> His sole purpose: to destroy the monsters that plague the world.
  <br><br> But not everything monstrous-looking is evil and not everything fair is good. . . and in every fairy tale there is a grain of truth.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.summaryOverlay` isn't child of `.summary`, as you stated here:

```
.summary:hover .summaryOverlay {
  display: block;
}
```

So you need to hover in `.leftAlign` (`.summary`'s parent) which is the `.summaryOverlay` sibling, you need for that to use the [adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

**Note**: remove the inline styles, they are a bad practice to use them

```css
.summary:hover {
  opacity: .6;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.summaryOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 280px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #E7DFDD;
  color: #0E0B16;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: .9;
  -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.leftAlign:hover + .summaryOverlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftAlign" id="lastWish">
  <img class="summary" alt="the last wish" src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
</div>
<div class="summaryOverlay">
  Geralt is a witcher.
  <br><br> &nbsp;Yet he is no ordinary killer-for-hire.
  <br><br> His sole purpose: to destroy the monsters that plague the world.
  <br><br> But not everything monstrous-looking is evil and not everything fair is good. . . and in every fairy tale there is a grain of truth.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is *not* asking the browser to display the `div` on hovering over the image as you intended. Rather, it is asking the browser to display a *child* of `.summary` which has a class `summaryOverlay`. `img` can't ever have a child element, can it? Even if it could, `.summaryOverlay` is not its child. So, it won't work as you intended. Try this:

```css
#lastWish:hover + .summaryOverlay{
  display:block;
}
```

Barring any CSS specificity issues, it should give you what want. Let me know how it goes.